# Duplicate Key Entey for key PRIMARY

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I am new to MySQL but learning fast. I am following a tutorial and all is well until I add a couple of records. I am doing this tutorial in Workbench 6.1.

This is what the tutorial ask me to do:

After creating a very simple table with emp_no, first_name and last_name where emp_no is the PK we insert three records:

```
no  fn      ln
--------------------
1   Daniel  Lamarche
2   Paul    Smith
3   Bobz    Youruncle
```

Then the tutorial asks us to UPDATE the third record to:

```
5   Alan    Youruncle
```

All is well. Then it asks us to confirm that LAST_INSERT_ID() is still equal to 3.

The table now looks like the following:

```
no  fn      ln
--------------------
1   Daniel  Lamarche
2   Paul    Smith
5   Alan    Youruncle
```

Here where I have a problem that the tutorial does not address because it stops there. Adventurous as I am I wonder what will happen if I add three records. Since LAST_INSERT_ID = 3 will the emp_no will take 3, 4 then 6 I ask myself.

So when I insert three records with:

```
INSERT INTO employees (first_name, last_name)
VALUES ('Paul', 'Lalo'), ('Claude', 'Baker'), ('Alan', 'Brown');
```

I get the error ERROR Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '5' for key PRIMARY.

Now I do perfectly understand why there is an error. Anyone can help me understand how to deal with this. Is there a way to insert new records and skip the value that it encounters?

Now I also understand that maybe it is not good practice to do this that way or whatever. But let's pretend that this is a real life situation and not just a fun tutorial for beginners like me.

Just in case someone wants to the tut is at: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sequence/

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

In most real life situations you would never update or insert an auto_increment primary key value, you would just update or insert the other column values. It is only there as a pointer to the row.

When the tutorial asks you to UPDATE the third record to:

```
5   Alan    Youruncle
```

It is only highlighting a point about the behaviour of LAST_INSERT_ID(), but should point out that this is not an UPDATE that you should generally run.

If you want to completely change a row, you would generally do a delete followed by an insert.

If you must, you can change the current auto_increment value on a table to one higher than the current maximum. This only becomes necessary if you have done something unusual however:

```
ALTER TABLE employees AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight Arth. This makes absolute sense that they only wanted to illustrate the point of LAST_INSERT_ID(). I suppose one can find out the highest emp_no by sorting in DESC and using LIMIT 1.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when you perform an `INSERT` MySQL will update the table's `AUTO_INCREMENT`. When you perform an update on an "auto increment" column MySQL won't update the table's `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Therefore,

`INSERT INTO users(id, name) VALUES(20, 'John');` Will update the `AUTO_INCREMENT` to `21` so the next insert will have the 21st ID.

But if you perform an update `UPDATE users SET id = 40 WHERE id = 20` the `AUTO_INCREMENT` still will be `21` not `41` and the next insert will have the 21st ID. If you keep inserting eventually you'll hit the 40th ID again and it will raise a duplicated primary key exception.

Also, FWIW, `AUTO_INCREMENT` updates are calculated and performed after inserts and not before.

Comment: Thanks Ben. This is very clear. I'll look into how to change AUTO_INCREMENT to another value manually to a value 1 higher than the highest ID.

Comment: @DLamarche if you set `AUTO_INCREMENT` to a value lower than the highest ID it'll automatically set it to the next highest ID. No need for over-complicated queries or calculations.

Comment: Even better. Thanks.
Hope one of these days I'll be able to repay by helping someone else.
Thank you again for this insight.